# Mapster, try map to field of class with many constructor without default and fail

Tags: c#, .net, mapster

I'm try to learn Mapster. I have classes like this

```
class In
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
}

class Out
{
    public Sub Sub;
    public string C;
}

class Sub
{
    public string A; 
    public string B;
    
    public Sub(string a, string b)
        =>(A,B) = (a,b);
}
```

Create a config:

```
var mapper = new Mapper();

mapper.Config
    .ForType<In, Out>()
    .Map(@out => @out.C, @in=> @in.C)
    .Map(@out=> @out.Sub, @in => new Sub(@in.A, @in.B));
```

Now, if I try map object - everythink is ok, but if I add second costructor to `Sub` class

```
class Sub
{
    public string A; 
    public string B;
    
    public Sub(string a, string b)
        =>(A,B) = (a,b);

    public Sub(string a)=> A=a;
}
```

Mapster throe exception in runtime:

```
Error while compiling
source=UserQuery+In
destination=UserQuery+Out
type=Map

Error while compiling
source=UserQuery+Sub
destination=UserQuery+Sub
type=Map
No default constructor for type 'Sub', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'
```

I try read the docs, about `ConstructUsing` and `MapWith` and this is something not what I need (or am I doing something wrong). How I can do this?

Comment: If I add a default constructor, everything goes like clockwork. But in my real task - I can't do this.

Comment: I have never used this library, but have you tried `.MapToConstructor(true)` see if this page helps https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Constructor-mapping

Comment: I understand this applies to the root object itself. And it doesn't fit my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found. Just use

```
config.ForType<Sub, Sub>().MapToConstructor(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the `MapToConstructor(true)` to Mapster GlobalSettings:

`TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.MapToConstructor(true);`